# Accessing Attribute Values of a View

Tags: android, view, textview

Is there any possible way to access attribute values of a view through the object..

```
       android:text="@string/example"
```

I need to access this value from an object. I tried many options but none of them returning '@string/example' this value.

I need to find which resource is being used by this text view.. so if I can access this text view attribute value of a textview object.. that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
String s = myTextView.getText();

if(s.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.yourString){
}
else if() ...
```

This should work. If you have a lot of texts to choose from you can also try switch statement.

Comment: thank you..but this doesn't solve my problem.i need to dynamically check every textview on a  layout which shares a common property..such as string resources that start with naming convention 'test_'... for example if there is 2 textviews that using 'test_HAI','test_Hello' respectively.i need to check all textviews that using this convention

Comment: you should use the tag field for such convention

Answer (score 0):

U cannot get resource id from text content....It's just like looking for a name using byte stream.
I followed Pedro's advice and have some sort of fix.....->

```
        TextView vt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.andry_tv);
          vt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    v.setTag(R.string.app_name+"");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getResourceName(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("oye", e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Explanation->
u can set that id (which ur are using to set text in textview) to set as tag.
Then use getResources().getResouceName function to get resource name from that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Resources.getXml(int)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)) and then parse a resource as xml. Here is a common example of SAX parser, adopt it for your case:

```
{
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.example);

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            System.out.println("Start document");
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            System.out.println("Start tag " + xpp.getName());
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            System.out.println("End tag " + xpp.getName());
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            System.out.println("Text " + xpp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    System.out.println("End document");
}
```